# python 2.7 is still default though alias python=python3.4 is set

Tags: 14.04, command-line, python

I have set alias python=python3.4. but still when I write python in terminal it executes as version 2.7.

python3.4 only works in the terminal window where alias python=python3.4 is set.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting an alias is essentially a user shortcut and does not affect your environment outside of your terminal[(see description of 'alias' here)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).  Your question doesn't explain what the 'end goal' is, so I'll answer the two I can think of.

1. If you only interested in a shortcut:**Don't do it!**  Just use 'python3.4' - it's 3 more keystrokes...
2. If you want to use version 3.4 by default *outside* your terminal:

First, you need to do is change the symlink of /usr/bin/python to point to the correct python version.

```
  unalias python
  ls -al $(which python)
```

Output should be something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 01 00:01 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

You need to change the link ("/usr/bin/python") to point to the python3.4 version:

```
sudo ln -f -v /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python
```

**IMPORTANT** - you are changing the executable python version universally!  Be sure you don't have any applications that depend on the older version's libraries.  If, for example, you've installed the libpython2.7-dev package, then this is a *CRAY CRAY BAD IDEA!* Never mix versions of executables and build resources or you will get weird behavior...